# Linux ntpd leap second preparation

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd, gps, leapsecond

There will be a leap second on June 30, 2015 at 23:59:60 UTC.

I have a Linux based stratum 1 NTP server which uses GPS as a reference clock. The server is using the "default" ntp.org `ntpd`.

How should I prepare for the leap second to ensure that the correct time is available at and after the leap second?

Will the `ntpd` server behave correctly?

If uncertain, is there a way to test this beforehand?

Comment: The world wonders...

Comment: Luckily there were not that many hiccups this time. It was much worse in 2012. However this question still remains valid for the next round. Hopefully one day they stop this craziness and abolish leap seconds.

Comment: That's easy. Just go stabilize the rotation of the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

There is some explanation [here](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo-real.htm#AEN2499)

Looks like you will need to check the kernel settings etc and if all is in order ntpd will take care of things. Your application layer might need more thought though.